# Check if a value exists before updating a column for a already existing record in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, mysql2

Lets say I have table called **Tokens**,  with columns: **id**, **refresh_token**, and **token**. refresh_token column should be unique. But we may have many refresh_token fields that are null. These null refresh_token fields should be updated later, but there is a possibility that we may try to enter a refresh_token value that is contained in another field, and that will cause a conflict.

So, what I wanted to do is:

- First check if the refresh_token value is contained in any other
  fields.
- If it is not contained or if unique, the that new refresh_token value can be used to update a specific row with a given id.
- If the value is not unique then we can do something else.

This is how I did it, but i am not sure if it is the best way. Maybe you can advise and give a little explanation about your answer.

```ruby
    if con.query("(SELECT id FROM Tokens WHERE refresh_token='#{refresh_token}') LIMIT 1;").count == 1
       # do something important here
    else
        con.query("UPDATE Tokens SET refresh_token='#{refresh_token}' WHERE id='#{id}';")
    end
```

this is done using ruby.

Comment: `UPDATE x SET tok='new_val' WHERE tok='old_val'` will not update anything unless `tok='old_val'` exists. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following statements to perform a check before updating.

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Tokens WHERE Token = ''))  
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO Tokens(token,..,..) 
        VALUES(val1,val2,val3) 
    END 
    END
```

OR

```
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Tokens WHERE Token = ''))  
        BEGIN 
            update Tokens
           SET token = myVal
        END 
        END
```

Not sure what you need. Hope any one of the above helps you :)

Comment: Those are procedural IFs, which require a stored procedure.

Comment: I thought he was using a Stored procedure. Did not see properly. My Bad.

Comment: I am not using a stored procedure. I want to do this using one query.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the update like this:

```
UPDATE Tokens
SET refresh_token = 'C08Rbs'
WHERE id = '2'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT refresh_token FROM Tokens WHERE refresh_token = 'C08Rbs')
```

Use [`ROW_COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) to determine if any rows were actually updated. Assuming the row where id = 2 actually exists, it will return 0 if no rows were updated (because the value already exists).

The `ROW_COUNT()` function is also provided in the MySQL API (as `mysql_affected_rows()`), so your programming language of choice will have a function to return the same thing, and generally the result of an `UPDATE` will return the number of affected rows.

Normally, you use a unique index to avoid duplicates on a particular column or columns and simply try to update:

```
UPDATE IGNORE Tokens
SET refresh_token = 'C08Rbs'
WHERE id = 2
```

Using `IGNORE` keeps you from getting an error on a duplicate value, the update won't occur, and it will still return the number of rows actually updated. It will return 1 on success and 0 on failure.

It's still strange that you're changing a "NULL" value rather than inserting a new record.

You haven't said what you want to do if the value already exists.

Comment: thanks marcus, I will explain. I have a table column named access_token and another called token. the access_token column should be holding unique values, but can be having NULL value too. Later someone can enter values of the blank refresh_tokens. (BTW these refresh tokens are got from the corresponding tokens in the same row), You know oauth2 access_tokens.

Comment: If another refresh_token exists, it means that the token belongs to the same user. therefore that row is deleted and nothing is done. But if the refresh_token got from a token is unique, we will update that token row and add that refresh_token. I will show you what I have done, because I am now sure if is the most optimal way. Check the question update

Comment: @ben, the method you're using is fine and pretty much standard for that type of action in code. For peformance index the `refresh_token` column. For a minute performance improvement, if you're not using the returned `id`, use `SELECT 1` so that less data is sent between the server and app/web server.